# RESTful/token-based WebAPI authentication instead of WebSecurity.Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a smallish AngularJS web application with a C# backend which is working all right as far as it goes; I handle authentication in a cookie-based fashion with [WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx), using

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);
```

for new accounts,

```
WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
```

for logging in,

```
WebSecurity.Logout();
```

for logout, and

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId();
```

to get the user ID on a particular request.

As I said, this is all working well as far as it goes, but it feels fragile, not to mention that it doesn't work for any sort of RESTful use of my backend. (For instance, I would like to hit the API from a mobile app at some point in the future.) None of this is my area of specialty (which is how it ended up like this in the first place) so I am in search of advice.

I'd like to transition to some sort of token-based authentication instead to make the authentication process more context-agnostic. Does the WebSecurity class even have this capability? Is this class a good approach? If not, what might be a good strategy for transitioning to something better? I've been Googling my head off about this and am seeing a lot of terms thrown around without having good context for any of them.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

May be you are familiar with next tutorials, but they will give you full picture of token based authentication.
ASP.NET Identity 2.1 with ASP.NET Web API 2.2 (Accounts Management) – 
[Part 1](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/)
[Part 2](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/03/asp-net-identity-2-accounts-confirmation-password-user-policy-configuration/)
[Part 3](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/)

1. Ask server for token (http://youhost/oauth/token)
2. Server issues token with specified expiration (configurable by you)
3. Sends token to client with details about expiration
4. Store token in browser db for future use
5. Attach received token to your requests

Also you can refresh tokens using described next [tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/). By the way, they also have expiration option

Thanks to TAISEER for his hard work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to upgrade, presuming you are not already on it, to ASP.net 4.5.1 or greater ASP.net is now shipping with OAuth support out the box. This will allow you to let the user log in via a MS id, Facebook, twitter or other OAuth2 providers (i.e token based auth).

Although I don't like doing this, just in case the link breaks for future reader, the following article is a good tutorial on how Oauth2 works with Asp.net. Unfortunately it is too long to post here.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services